# Call test case does not work

Tags: web-services, testing, groovy, soapui

It is explained here how to run one step of a testcase in same test suite

[Is it possible to run specific test steps in other Test Cases from a Groovy Script test step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047403/is-it-possible-from-groovy-script-test-step-to-run-specific-test-steps-in-other)

I want to run all steps of a test  case in another test suite : how ?

I tried to reference testsuite with testSuites ["my test suite"] but it does not like

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script from the [link](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=3688), assuming that suite name, case name are "TestSuite 1", "TestCase 1" respectively

```
def tCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite 1"].testCases["TestCase 1"]
tCase.run((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go by the following to run a particular step,

```
projectName = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
tSuite = projectName.testSuites["RequiredTestSuiteName"]
tCase = tSuite.testCases["RequiredTestCaseName"]
tStep = tCase.testSteps["RequiredTestStepName"]
tStep.run(testRunner, context)
```